# How to I use horizontal scroll view in a XML based Android app?

Tags: android, xml, android-viewpager

Correct me if I'm wrong but I want to be able to swipe through pages in my app like flashcards but with the phone vertical. I'm assuming that I would use horizontal scroll view but I don't know how to use it and can't find any good info. If you could just give me the basic code for 3 pages that would be great. (I'm using XML)

Answer (score 1):

Read this [post on the ViewPager](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html). You'll need the compatibility library, but it sounds like exactly what you're looking for.